# Rails Search Field of Polymorphic belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my model Patient, it has a role through a polymorphic association, called roleable. And that role has a belongs_to: user. I need to search by last_name on that User model...

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :role, :as => :roleable, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :role
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

    belongs_to :roleable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
```

How would I form that query so that I could search by the first name of User? This is what I have thus far in my Patient model:

```
def self.search(query)
    items = Patient.joins(role: :user).where('first_name LIKE :search OR last_name LIKE :search', search: query)
end
```

My main confusion is on the .joins part, and how to get User involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track but you need to specify which table you want the WHERE condition to apply to:

```
def self.search(query)
  Patient.joins(role: :user)
         .where('users.first_name LIKE :q OR users.last_name LIKE :q', q: "%#{query}%")
end
```

Creating a local variable and explicitly returning it is also completely superfluous since Ruby returns the last value implicitly.

Note that LIKE is case sensitive. If you are using Postgres you might want to use ILIKE instead to perform a case-insensitive search. On other DBs cast the value to lowercase:

```
def self.search(query)
  Patient.joins(role: :user)
         .where('LOWER("users.first_name") LIKE :q OR LOWER("users.last_name") LIKE :q', q: "%#{query.downcase}%")
end
```

Comment: Argh, I was even closer than I thought, because I was doing user.first_name, thinking that i needed to do singular because of belongs_to. But totally forgetting that's not how SQL works... thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When querying against a joined table like this, you need to prepend the table name to the columns belonging to the joined table:

```
def self.search(query)
  Patient.joins(role: :user).
      where('users.first_name LIKE :search OR users.last_name LIKE :search', search: query)
end
```